# Pandas single match join

Tags: python, pandas

There is a way to have a single first available match join? something that will create the final df inside the functions 'some_magic_merge'

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'joincol':['a','a','b','b','b','b','d','d'],
                    'val1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'joincol':['a','a','a','b','b','d'],
                    'val2':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

final_df = some_magic_merge(df1,df2)

print(final_df)
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

output final df

```
  joincol  val1  val2
0       a     1   1.0
1       a     2   2.0
2       b     3   4.0
3       b     4   5.0
4       b     5   NaN
5       b     6   NaN
6       d     7   6.0
7       d     8   NaN
```

output df1 and df2

```
  joincol  val1
0       a     1
1       a     2
2       b     3
3       b     4
4       b     5
5       b     6
6       d     7
7       d     8
  joincol  val2
0       a     1
1       a     2
2       a     3
3       b     4
4       b     5
5       d     6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for helper columns filled by counter and then left join in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
final_df = pd.merge(df1.assign(g=df1.groupby('joincol').cumcount()),
                    df2.assign(g=df2.groupby('joincol').cumcount()), 
                    how='left', on=['joincol','g']).drop('g', axis=1)
print(final_df)
  joincol  val1  val2
0       a     1   1.0
1       a     2   2.0
2       b     3   4.0
3       b     4   5.0
4       b     5   NaN
5       b     6   NaN
6       d     7   6.0
7       d     8   NaN
```